# Area51 profile not updating

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, area-51, statistics

I've noticed that the [Area51 site profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) for [RPG.StackExchange.com](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is not updating.  The question counts are definitely not up to date, as we have 614 questions, and the page only shows 582.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch! We recently introduced a bug in which none of the beta site stats were properly updating on Area 51. It's fixed now.