# How often are the “progress” pages updated on Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

There are now [pages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles) on area 51 that shows the status of beta sites, e.g. the number of questions.   They seem to be a bit out of date (not by just a few hours), e.g. the number of questions for Bicycles is wrong.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67928/area51-profile-not-updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress/stats pages on Area 51 are updated hourly.

A couple days ago, we [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67928/area51-profile-not-updating/67982#67982) a bug that prevented the pages from updating for a few days, which is likely what you were noticing.